# Retrieve a Google+ User's profile image url from Android/iOS using the correct API key

Tags: android, ios, google-api, google-plus

We have a leaderboard that has user's who've signed in from Facebook, Twitter, and Google+ (via GMail).  All the signin is perfectly fine and working, but we're getting this frustrating bit when we try to get other user's image URL, when we're *not* logged in with Google+.

Basically, just `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/1234567890?fields=image`.  For testing purposes, and during development on the desktop, we can use our general purpose, server key which has no IP-locking, and it again works perfectly, `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/1234567890?fields=image&key=<CREDENTIAL SERVER KEY>`, but this is a key we'd obviously prefer not to share out at all, if possible.

```
com.sixminute.freeracing.test D/HTTP GET﹕ https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/1234567890?fields=image&key=<CREDENTIAL ANDROID KEY>
com.sixminute.freeracing.test D/HTTP RESPONSE﹕ {
    "error": {
    "errors": [
    {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
    }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
    }
    }
```

I get the exact same error if I use the `<CREDENTIAL IOS KEY>` in the URL instead.

For Android, the signing keys are definitely correct, for iOS, the bundle ids are definitely correct, but no matter what I try to do, I can't get this call to work correctly.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.. did you manage to solve it anyway??

Comment: @LucaDeNardi unfortunately not, no. I spoke to a few Google folks about it and the basic feedback was to use the proper API calls (not direct HTTP ones), or use a completely unlocked API key :/

Comment: I'll end up making the requests from the server..thanks!